# No final de frases, "mesmo" é precedido por vírgula?

Tags: pontuação

Sempre tive essa dúvida. Eu na maioria das vezes coloco vírgula e vejo muitas vezes assim, mas já também vi muitas vezes sem vírgula:

> — Será que vai chover?
>   — Não, acho que continuará ensolarado, mesmo.

Ou

> — Não, acho que continuará ensolarado mesmo.

Então, "mesmo" leva ou não vírgula?

Comment: Eu aí não colocava vírgula, a menos que quisesse indicar uma pausa especialmente marcada na fala. Mas o meu emprego das vírgulas é muito heterodoxo.

Comment: @Jacinto heterodoxo como assim?

Comment: @JorgeB. [*heterodoxo* 1](http://www.aulete.com.br/heterodoxo) = que não segue as normas , oposto de *ortodoxo* = de acordo com as normas.

Comment: Eu concordo com o @Jacinto. Mas ficou uma dúvida: você só está falando desse tipo de *mesmo* do exemplo, que acho que tem função de advérbio? Porque a regra pode variar conforme a função, se é que há regra.

Answer (score 2):

Ambos estão certos. Por isso você os encontra constantemente.

O caso é que o termo "mesmo" faz o papel de reforço da ideia.

O segundo caso

> — Não, acho que continuará ensolarado mesmo.

é menos enfático que o primeiro

> Não, acho que continuará ensolarado, mesmo

Uma análise morfosintática demonstrará que o termo derradeiro exerce papeis diferentes. Mas, pra simplificar, no primeiro caso, substitua o termo por "**sim**". No segundo, por **certamente**.